# SOQL query for fetching country, city of an account

Tags: soql, governorlimits

I am new to SOQL.
How do I fetch the country,state,city of an account?

I have tried this but have an error.

```
Select AccountNumber,name, BillingAddress.City from Account
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can found a list of all SOAP API fields accepted in Account (standard fields)

[Account SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm)

If you need the Billing Address fields you can use:

```
SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry FROM Account
```

or with ShippingAddress...

```
SELECT Id, Name, ShippingStreet, ShippingCity, ShippingState, ShippingPostalCode, ShippingCountry FROM Account
```

even you can retreive Longitude and Latitude from each one.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
BillingCity
BillingCountry
BillingState
```

are the correct API Names

To check the object's field correct API Name use describe call in developer console and check all fields label Name and corresponding API Name in debug log

```
for(Schema.SobjectField strFld: Account.SobjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().Values())
{
    system.debug('-----Label Name----'+strFld.getDescribe().getLabel()+'-------API Name--'+strFld.getDescribe().getName());
}
```

---

```
Select name, BillingCity, BillingCountry, BillingState from Account
```