# Best way to get city, state, and zip fields onto Account object?

Tags: account, address, country-and-state

The Account object doesn't have city, state, or zip standard fields. I can create those in custom fields, but feel like there should be a better way to do that?

We want to be able to pull a report of all our California accounts, or pull all the accounts on in a West Coast state.

What would be the best way to set that up?

Comment: You can find it in: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/119936/24998

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two standard composite address fields, either of which should suit your needs.

- `BillingAddress`

  - `BillingCity`
  - `BillingState`
  - `BillingPostalCode`
- `ShippingAddress`

  - `ShippingCity`
  - `ShippingState`
  - `ShippingPostalCode`

Once your fields are on the `Page Layout` and you have data populated, you can get this data via a query as follows. You can apply a similar filter in any `Report`.

```
SELECT BillingCity, BillingState, BillingPostalCode FROM Account WHERE BillingState = 'CA'
```

---

If you want to relabel these fields:

1. Go to `Customize` > `Tab Names and Labels` > `Rename Tabs and Labels`.
2. Next to `Accounts`, click the `Edit` link.
3. Click the <kbd>Next</kbd> button.
4. Change the labels as needed.
5. Click the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

Comment: Maybe a quick sample SoQL for the OP? :)

Comment: N.B. OP can also change the labels of the aforementioned fields if OP wanted to strip away the `Billing` or `Shipping` prefix using `Tab Names and Labels` in `Setup`

Comment: @crop Good point. I just re-labelled `Shipping` to `Primary`. I'll add steps for that.